# Removing a row containing a specific text in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a data set of around 3000 columns, but some of the columns have several cells that contain cells "na". These rows have no importance since they don't have data that I will need, is there a command in google sheets that can either highlight the entire row that contains that text or delete the entire row containing that text?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Example of columns that have <code>na</code> in cells, the row must be deleted]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u8OUfQOzgAulf1a8bzQ8SB5sb5Uvb1I4amF5sdGEBlc/edit?usp=sharing

My document ^.

Comment: You can use filter the data and copy paste in new sheet. hope you understand my point .

Comment: How many rows of data do you have? 3,000 columns is a fair bit, just for single row. The `match` function would work, but recalculation time could be an issue. If you are going to delete the row anyway, I'd opt for a script that detects "na" then deletes the row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this formula to color all `na` rows:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A1:$Z),,999^99)), " na "))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you again @player0, once more you were able to help me thanks ! as long as they are highlighted I can just filter them by color and delete them. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello, I ran the command and it has been highlighting the rows but it has only done 200 rows out of 7000. It has been already around 5 hours that I have left google sheets on. Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: can you try like this? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ud1QUq0fliq_I-SFV6cWvMp2ssKRMLbgEsxGS2yeOgo/copy

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, I don't know why my computer kept on taking forever to even highlight certain rows. You are a life saver.

Answer (score 2):

This answer based on what I understand, sorry if I'm wrong. You can use conditional formatting to highlight all NA text 
[image]

This is what rules I used

[image]

Here are another answers that may help you

1. [Delete a row in Google Spreadsheets if value of cell in said row is 0 or blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058019/delete-a-row-in-google-spreadsheets-if-value-of-cell-in-said-row-is-0-or-blank)
2. [Google Sheets: delete rows containing specified data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643965/google-sheets-delete-rows-containing-specified-data)
3. [Deleting Cells in Google Sheets without removing a whole row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112422/deleting-cells-in-google-sheets-without-removing-a-whole-row)

Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if my understing is well but see below what you can do.
This is a google script function which color the whole column where "na" is in

```
  function myFunction() {
//get the spreadsheet where the function is running
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  //Replace "the name of your sheet" by your sheet name" be careful its case sensitive.
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("The name of your sheet")
  //Get all your data as an array (If your sheet has no header, change 2 by 1 and (sheet.getLastRow()-1) by sheet.getLastRow())
  var values = sheet.getRange(2,1,(sheet.getLastRow()-1), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  //For each column
  for (var i = 0; i< sheet.getLastColumn(); i++){
  //using function map is helping to select one column by one column
    var mapValues = values.map(function(r){return r[i]});
    //Searching your keyword in the column, in your case it's "na"
    var position = mapValues.indexOf("Put the string that you are looking for, in your case 'na'");
    //if at least there is one "na" inside the column
    if( position >-1){
    //then this color have to get red color as a background
       var wholeColumn = sheet.getRange(2,(i+1),(sheet.getLastRow()-1));
       wholeColumn.setBackground("red");
    }
  }
}``
```

Let me know if it works